# Elasticsearch/Nest - Combining multiple range queries (OIC syntax)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

ES newbie here (transitioning over from the SolrNet world, so I am looking for pointers with a similar syntax)

Can anyone help with formulating a query that might look something like the code snippet below *without* the lambdas. Unfortunately there are very few examples in the plain old OI syntax and I have been stuck....

How would I formulate a set of boolean range queries, in solrnet I would do something like this to obtain items that fall in a certain price band:

```
    List<ISolrQuery> queryList = new List<ISolrQuery>();
    double[] priceList = GetPrices(..) //double array
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        queryList.Add(new solr.Query(new SolrQueryByRange<double>("price", priceList[i] * 0.95, priceList[i] * 1.15));
    }

    var results = _solr.Query(new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queryList), new QueryOptions
    {
        Rows = 50,
        Fields = new[] { "Item", "Created", "Price" },
    });
```

Could anyone help with equivalent Elasticsearch/Nest query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new ElasticClient(connection: new InMemoryConnection());

    // prices from your GetPrices method...
    var prices = new[] { 1d, 2d };

    var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Document>("index", "document")
    {
        Fields = new List<Nest.PropertyPathMarker>{ "Item", "Created", "Price" },
        Size = 50,
        Query = new BoolQuery
        {
            Should = prices.Select(p => new RangeQuery
            {
                Field = "price",
                GreaterThanOrEqualTo = (p * 0.95).ToString(),
                LowerThanOrEqualTo = (p * 1.15).ToString()
            }.ToContainer())
        }.ToContainer()
    };

    var result = client.Search<Document>(searchRequest);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.RequestInformation.Request));
}

public class Document
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

This searches for`"document"` types in index `"index"` (strongly typed to your `Document` POCO), using a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and should clauses of ranges constructed from the prices - if a document's `price` field falls into any one of the ranges, it will be considered a match.

The resulting query DSL from the NEST query above is

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "fields": [
    "Item",
    "Created",
    "Price"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": "0.95",
              "lte": "1.15"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": "1.9",
              "lte": "2.3"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: great answer. Thanks so much for helping out!